# How to mirror AWS traffic from container A into container B

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, vpc

I have an AWS traffic mirroring session that collects traffic from container A's ENI (elastic network interface) and sends it to container B's ENI.

Inside A, /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink outputs '8', and /sys/class/net/eni123/ifindex on the host also outputs '8', so eth0 from container A is eni123 on the host.

I can capture mirrored HTTP traffic directed to A using tcpdump -i eni123 from the host. But tcpdump on eth0 from B does not capture any packets. It does capture pings that I manually send from A to B.

I created container B with `securityContext: privileged: true`.

Are container eth interfaces restricted from capturing mirrored packets ? Should I use something other than a regular ENI as the mirror target ?

Comment: Which is the network mode you are using in AWS ECS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default docker networking mode is [Docker Bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers) which isolates the container from the network.

Launch container B with `--net=host` and it will be able to capture traffic between the network and host as required.

Answer (score 0):

The ENIS attached to the EC2 instances are in the root namespace.Whenever a new pod is created, a new namespace for that pod is created using a pause container and all the containers within that pod are part of that namespace.

So, while using the VPC traffic mirroring the traffic from one ENI will be mirrored to another ENI attached to the EC2 instance but the mirror target ENI would not push those networks to the virtual interfaces of the PODs which are in different namespaces.

As a workaround, in case of EKS, I deployed a pod with hostNetwork: true parameter for the container and the pod was able to access all the interfaces of the host and the tcpdump also displayed all the pod traffic.

Please try this approach and check if this approach suites your use case.

## Sample Pod manifest yaml for reference

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
```